# Laravel 7 "Class 'Form' not found"

Tags: php, laravel

**I went to work Laravel!
when I typed in my code**

```
{{ Form::token()   }}
```

**I got the message "Class 'Form' not found"!
I went to google to investigate this error but the results are all for laravel versions 4,5,6 nowhere for version 7
And that confuses me a bit I can’t orient myself!
Please Help me!**

**create.blade.php**

```
@section ('content')
    <form action="{{ URL::route('account-create-post') }}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
            {{ Form::token() }}
    </form>
@stop
```

Web.php

```
Route::group(array('brefore' => 'guest'), function() {

    Route::group(array('brefore' => 'csrf'), function(){

        Route::post('/account/create',array(
            'as' => 'account-create-post',
            'uses' => 'AccountController@postcreate'
        ));

    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using this for CSRF token?

Comment: Yes of course I use for CSRF!

Comment: Then try @csrf instead

Comment: You can just use `@csrf` if all you need is that token.

Comment: I don't understand where to apply msm is it instead of Form :: token ()

Comment: Yes remove {{ Form::token() }} and put @csrf

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason that you may get the error Class 'Form' not found is that you have not been registered the form on your config/app.php. You should register it if you have not done it yet.
here is an example:

```
'aliases' => [
...
// others
  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```

If you have not installed yet install it and register it.
you can add csrf token with other methods if you want.
You can use blade for this like this

```
 <form action="{{ URL::route('account-create-post') }}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
            @csrf
    </form>
```

If you need just token, you can get it with csrf_token() like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got the message "Class 'Form' not found"! I went to google to investigate this error but the results are all for laravel versions 4,5,6 nowhere for version 7 And that confuses me a bit I can’t orient myself!

No. You can only use the `Form` class maximum Laravel version 4.

**The `Form` and `HTML` helpers have been deprecated since Laravel 5**. However, there are community-driven replacements such as those maintained by the [Laravel Collective](http://laravelcollective.com).

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `@csrf` Blade directive to generate the token field:

```
<form action="{{ route('account-create-post') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    ...
</form>
```